# using python docs split

Tags: python, python-docx

I am looking to modify a program that currently uses python-docx to import text from a .txt file into a specific part of a .docx file. Currently I use a find_replace feature. I found on github an great looking project, but am having difficulty figuring out what I've done wrong thus far. Here is the project:

https://github.com/alllexx88/python-docx-split-run

Here's what I've written:

```
def insert_run_after(par, run, txt=''):
    """Insert a new run with text {txt} into paragraph after given {run}.

    Returns the newly created run.
    """
    run_2 = par.add_run(txt)
    run._r.addnext(run_2._r)

    return run_2

document = Document('Psychevaltemplate2.docx')
par = document.paragraphs[0]
run = par.runs[0]
background = input("what is the location of the background file?")

input_doc = Document(background)
insert_run_after(par, 5, 'TEST RESULTS:')
output_doc.save("sampleoutput2.docx")

exit()
```

and here's the error:

run._r.addnext(run_2._r)

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_r'

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Either `run` or `run_2` is an `int`, and so it doesn't have an `_r` object to reference.

Answer (score 0):

In the line: `insert_run_after(par, 5, 'TEST RESULTS:')` you are passing `5` as the `run` argument.

Maybe you mean this?

```
insert_run_after(par, par.runs[5], "TEST RESULTS:")
```

or possibly:

```
insert_run_at_position(par, 5, "TEST RESULTS:")
```

which is one of the other functions available in that project.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it.

Comment: EDIT: I see one of my obvious mistakes, and I'm working on it. Still dont get why the run index is out of range, though.

Comment: So I have part of this fixed. I can get a character inserted at the right position, but I dont want a character, I want a few paragraphs from another document.

another_run = insert_run_at_position(par, 0, 'e')

Essentially, I want some variable where 'e' is.